# Creating Index in Cloudant

Tags: cloudant

Scenario.
I have a document in the database which has thousands of item in

> 'productList'  as below.

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsilX.png)

All the object in array 'productList' has the same shape and same fields with different values.
Now I want to search in the following way.

- when a user writes 'c' against 'Ingrediants' field, the list will show all 'Ingrediants' start with alphabet 'c'.
- when a user write 'A' against 'brandName' field, the list will show
  all 'brandName' start with alphabet 'A'.

please give an example using this to search for it, either it is by

- creating an index(json,text).
- creating a Search index (design document) or
- using views etc

Note: I don't want to create an index at run-time(I mean index could be defined by Cloudant dashboard) I just want to query it, by this library in the application.

I have read the documentation's, I got the concepts.
Now, I want to implement it with the best approach.
I will use this approach to handle all such scenarios in future.

Sorry if the question is stupid :)

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

CouchDB isn't designed to do exactly what you're asking.  You'd need one index for Ingredient, and another for Brand Name - and it isn't particularly performant to do both at once.  The best approach I think would be to check out the Mango query feature http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/api/database/find.html, try the queries you're interested in and then add indexes as required (it has the explain plan to help make this more efficient).